# Scala Modifiers and Type parametrization

Tags: scala

I'm creating a memoization class.

Each class memoizes a function type and has the following definition:

```
 class MemoizedFunction1[-T1, +R](f: T1 => R) {
    private[this] val cache = mutable.Map[T1, R]()
    def apply(t: T1): R = cache.getOrElseUpdate(t,f(t))
  }
```

This compiles nicely and works as expected.
However, if I remove the modified `private[this]` I get the following error:

```
contravariant type T1 occurs in invariant position in type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[T1,R] of value cache
```

Why is that, when I remove the modifier, suddenly the contravariant type T1 interferes with the invariant type of the Map?
How do modifiers affect type parametrization?

Comment: Tangential: `cache.getOrElseUpdate(t,f(t))` - I believe this will invoke `f(t)` every time, whether or not it's in the cache. Needs more laziness.

Comment: Actually it is a call by name parameter (according to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Map.html) which means that it doesn't get evaluated if `getOrElseUpdate` wants to. Further testing verified this.

Comment: Ah you're right. I need to familiarize myself more with Scala.

Comment: I'm a newbie, this may not make sense... but is the key parameter on the getter for cache ambiguous outside of the context of "this" instance?  If, for instance, I referenced a MemoizedFunction[String, String] as a MemoizedFunction[Object,String], it seems like the cache type would be off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I understand all of it, but this is addressed in section 4.5 (Variance Annotations) of the [Scala Language Specification 2.9](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) on page 45

> *References to the type parameters in object-private or object-protected values, variables, or methods (§5.2) of the class are not checked for their variance position. In
>   these members the type parameter may appear anywhere without restricting its legal variance annotations.*

To simplify your example, according to the spec, this is fine:

```
class Inv[T]

class Foo[-T] {
  private[this]   val a: Inv[T] = sys.error("compiles")
  protected[this] val b: Inv[T] = sys.error("compiles")
}
```

But if you remove `[this]` it will complain. At some level it makes sense since if it is not object private or protected the contravariant return type could leak outside the object and cause a runtime error.

Comment: So its a matter of encapsulation. Variance is contained hence no problem. Awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume you can remove `[this]`.

Without `[this]` you can add method `getOtherCache`:

```
class MemoizedFunction1[-T1, +R](f: T1 => R) { 
  private val cache = mutable.Map[T1, R]() // trait Map[A, B] extends Iterable[(A, B)] with Map[A, B] with MapLike[A, B, Map[A, B]]
  def apply(t: T1): R = cache.getOrElseUpdate(t,f(t))

  def getOtherCache(other: MemoizedFunction1[T1, R]) {
    val otherCache: mutable.Map[T1, R] = other.cache;
  }
}

class A
class B extends A

val mf1: MemoizedFunction1[B, B] = new MemoizedFunction1[B, B](b => b)

val mf2: MemoizedFunction1[B, B] = new MemoizedFunction1[A, B](a => new B)
// mf2 is MemoizedFunction1[B, B]
// mf2 contains mutable.Map[A, B]

mf1.getOtherCache(mf2) //Error! mf2.cache is NOT mutable.Map[B, B]!
```

Comment: Good example.
I checked the source (https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/mutable/Map.scala#L1) and no variance whatsoever. So it makes sense that your example gives an error.
Thank you for this information.

Comment: @JaimeJorge: It may sound silly, but do you know that there is online documentation? It is more convenient than source code: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map

Comment: :) I know. I just looked at the code to be sure of the variance (in case the API documentation withheld any variance annotation).
Looking at (for example) http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html I now know that it is explicit in the API

Comment: @JaimeJorge: Without code or documentation: key type parameter of Map just can't be contravariance. `Map[A, B]` can't be `Map[B, B]` because of `keys` method that returns `Iterable[TKey]`.

Answer (score 2):

[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) touches on this topic in Section [19.7 Object private data](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.7): "object private members can be accessed only from within the object in which they are defined. It turns out that accesses to variables from the same object in which they are defined do not cause problems with variance."